# Android AsyncTask Overload

Tags: android, for-loop, android-asynctask

i'm working on an app to load an amount of images from SD card using AsyncTask + for loop, I've test the app on my Galaxy Nexus, the app working perfectly, but it will crash if i use more than 33 loop

my question is: is there a limitation for using AsyncTask???,,, is there any thing wrong in my code cause the crash over 33 loops?

please help, here is my code:

```
ImageView iv;
TextView tv;
String picsDir;
int picsAmount;
String [] list;File dir;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //images folder
    picsDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/aFolder";

    // total images 
    picsAmount = 70;

    iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

    list = new String [picsAmount];
    dir = new File (picsDir);           

    // String array of my images names
    list = dir.list();

    new loadingImgs().execute(list);
}

class loadingImgs extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // nothing
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {

        String dir1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/aFolder";

        String[] theList = params;
        Bitmap[] bmp = new Bitmap[picsAmount];
        Drawable[] drw = new Drawable[picsAmount];

        tv.setText("dir1="+dir1+"  found= "+picsAmount);            
        File dir = new File(dir1);          



        for (int i = 0; i < picsAmount; i++){
            bmp[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(dir+"/"+theList[i]);
            drw[i] = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp[i]);        
        }           

        return drw[0];
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {

        // set drw[0] as iv image
        iv.setImageDrawable(result);


        };

}
```

}

Comment: Could you please specify what do you mean by "crash"? Can you post your stack trace?

Comment: It crashes with memory overflow exception?

Comment: Yeah unless those images are tiny you're probably running out of memory.  There's no real solution to that, other than not loading that many images at once.  Do you really need all of them on screen at the same time?  If not, an LRUCache to hold the ones on screen and loading on demand will work better.

Comment: that's right, in Log-cat: dalvikvm-heap Out of memory on 3456016-byte allocation, what is the deal now?? i'm doing for loop because i have so many images, i don't want to import them one by one, that's why i used for loop, what should i do or modify to use the for loop in this situation

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error do you get when crashing?

Is it an "OutOfMemoryException"?

There is certainly not hard limits on the number of loops you can use :)

You are simply allocating too much space on the heap, probably more than what your device can handle per app.

Use `getMemoryClass()` on `ActivityManager`to get more info about the specifics of your environment.

Comment: will, you r right, i've around 600mb of ram, but the images so small, the total size of them around 3mb, also each one of them around 30kb, how can i avoid this error while using for loop for fast importation

Comment: The total size you mentioned is probably for compressed PNG or JPEG images. Bitmaps are uncompressed and take four bytes for each pixel in memory. I guess your images are 720×1200, that makes 3.3 MiB for each image.

Comment: @user3843006 You certainly have nowhere close to 600mb of RAM available. Most phones these days have a limit of 24MB per app/linux process. Check the ActivityManager documentation.

Answer (score 0):

`Bitmap`s [use huge amounts of memory](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html). You should avoid having so many of them in memory at the same time.

Comment: what should i do, i wanna load more than 100 image using for loop, is there is any why to avoid this error?

Comment: Why do you need 100 images at the same time in memory? Use the `for` loop and in each iteration, load the bitmap, create drawable from it and recycle the bitmap.